# JiBX bindings lost when deploying jar dependency in Eclipse WTP

Tags: eclipse-wtp, m2e, jibx

I am using Elipse Indigo, maven 2.2.1, m2e 1.0.2, maven integration for wtp 0.15.2, m2e connector for JiBX 1.2.3.

I have a shared maven jar artifact which contains jibx bindings. 
The .project file for this looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>my-binding</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
            <buildCommand>
                <name>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder</name>
            <arguments>
                </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.jibx.eclipse.JibxBindingBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
        <nature>org.jibx.eclipse.JibxNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>
    </natures>
    </projectDescription>
```

I have followed the instructions given to set up the [m2e Maven Eclipse Plugin](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/maven-jibx-plugin/m2e.html). I used the build-helper-maven-plugin (with eclipse connector) to include the generated-sources on the source folder.

When I compile this in eclipse, the JiBX binding runs ok - I can see the output in the JiBX console and the modified classes in the target/classes directory.

I then use this generated jar in a war artifact.

The project file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>my-webapp</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.javascriptValidator</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

My generated `org.eclipse.wst.common.component` file is (in part):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
    <wb-module deploy-name="my-webapp">
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/main/webapp" tag="defaultRootSource"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/java"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/resources"/>
        <dependent-module archiveName="my-binding-1.79.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" deploy-path="/WEB-INF/lib" handle="module:/resource/my-binding/my-binding">
            <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
        </dependent-module>
        <property name="context-root" value="my-webapp"/>
        <property name="java-output-path" value="/my-webapp/target/classes"/>
    </wb-module>
</project-modules>
```

I run wtp with the 'Serve modules without publishing' and the 'Never publish automatically' options set.
When trying to reference the jibx-modified classes in the jar, I get the standard `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` when referencing the JiBX generated methods. The target directory of the binding project still contains the jibx-modified class files.

It might be a wrong path, but when I modify the .project file of the jar artifact to skip the wtp added natures, it seems to work, i.e. rebuilding the my-binding project with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>my-binding</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.jibx.eclipse.JibxBindingBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
        <nature>org.jibx.eclipse.JibxNature</nature>
    </natures>
    </projectDescription>
```

.. restart the webapp, and it works ok. Rebuild the webapp, and the natures are added back into the binding project and it is broken again.

I am missing a trick here (I had hoped the old wtp-eclipse dance was a thing of the past). Any ideas?

**Update:**
After further playing I have narrowed this down to broken bindings on shared classes

When building from the command line, it seems that all the bindings get built at once (or at least don't change the classes in the dependency jars), but when building through the eclipse plugin the various projects "wipe out the information from the earlier bindings", as per the Structured bindings section of [this](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/binding/tutorial/binding-advanced.html) - the factory classes get broken.

I am working to pull the common classes bindings into precompiled includes, but it is not a small job - we have quite a lot of shared classes and someone is bound to miss a shared object binding when making changes. Is there any way the bindings associated with each project can be labelled (named?) so that multiple factory classes can exist in the common class package rather than overwriting them, i.e.

```
com.alfonzo.common 
    shared.class
    foobar1_JiBX_bindingFactory.class
    foobar2_jibx_bindingFactory.class
```

So then project foobar1, building bindings including the shared class could reference it's factory, and project foobar2 reference an different one.

Or have I misunderstood this completely?...

Comment: Alfonzo, we need to see you maven pom.xml file to figure this out.

Comment: Apologies Don - I missed the notification of your comment. I have narrowed this down to broken bindings on shared classes and have updated the question. It might be a different question now...